# Webhooks/Callbacks in Joomla

Tags: joomla, webhook

This chunk of [code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-joomla/blob/c2b8d467123ea7ad424daeff257eccca50e0ec49/site/civicrm.php#L51) requiring a session on a POST request causes call backs from various 3rd party providers to fail. It has an exception for payment IPNs (civicrm/payment/ipn).

```
  // check and ensure that we have a valid session
  if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $urlStart = substr(stripslashes(CRM_Utils_Array::value('task', $_GET)), 0, 19);
    // the session should not be empty
    // however for standalone forms, it will not have any CiviCRM variables in the
    // session either, so dont check for it
    if (empty($_SESSION) && $urlStart != 'civicrm/payment/ipn') {
      $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
      CRM_Utils_System::redirect($config->userFrameworkBaseURL);
    }
  }
```

1. Is this code block necessary?
2. If so, is there a way to add other paths as exception?

Here are a couple of extension I have noticed that fail.

- https://github.com/teamsinger/uk.teamsinger.civicrm.mailgun (civicrm/mailgun/drop)
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/twilio-sms-provider (civicrm/sms/callback)

Comment: Not an answer to the main question, but that mailgun extension is quite old.  You might be interested in https://github.com/artfulrobot/mailgunny

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you. I have been wondering how long the legacy webhooks in Mailgun would survive.